# How do i connect to mysql data base with EJB entity bean?

Tags: java, mysql, database, ejb, entity-bean

How to configure ejb with mysql database?
I want to access mysql database table using EJB entity beans

Comment: Your question is much too vague. Which version of entity beans are you using? 1.x, 2.x, 3.x? On which application server? Isn't it explained in the book or tutorial you're using to develop your entity beans?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use JPA to manage your databade layer. 
   You can use Eclipselink or hibernate to implement JPA.
2. Create connection pool
3. Inject EntityManager in Session bean
4. From here you are ready to access databade